# Organizes div-element

Tags: html, css

I have a question about how to organize my div elements.

I have drawn a picture, where you can see a phone and four texts. Here is what I want: http://i61.tinypic.com/14spc2c.jpg

But when I'm trying to code it, I end up with this: http://i57.tinypic.com/2i0cgzk.png

I have searched all over the web, but I can't find any solution. I'm awere of using "margin" but with any resolution that do not fit mine, it will look weird.

Can anyone help me? :)

Answer (score 0):

Encapsulate the texts in divs and then use float css property.

Comment: Each text is in each div :-)